# .Net Framework 3.5 is needed for installing my VB 2008 Project?

Tags: visual-studio

Using VS 2008

I created a setup file for my Project, I run the setup file in my system, and My Project is working fine.

If I install my project to another system, is asking .Net Framework 3.5 at the setup time. 
.Net Framework 3.5 is needed for installing my Project?

Before i installing my project, i install the .net framework 3.5, It taking to much time to setup?

How to solve this? or any other way to create a Project setup ?

Can any one help to solve my setup problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is important for you that your program does ot require .NET 3.5, you can set up your project to target .NET 2.0. The the setup project will also see this, and (hopefully) remove the dependency when you update it.

If your project is VB.NET, you can set the **Target Framework** version here:
Project Properties -> Compile -> Advanced Compile Options...

If Your project is C#, it is here:
Project Properties -> Application

If you do this, of course you will not have available any .NET 3 specific functionality.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is right click on the setup project in the SolutionExplorer and select the Properties menu option.  You can then click on the Prerequisites button.  This allows you to control what your setup program needs/wants in order to install your code.

If you don't need .NET 3.5 then just unselect it.  This is just one more annoying thing that VS2008 does, you select .NET 2.0 as your target framework but it leaves .NET 3.5 as a pre-req.

Answer (score 0):

Do you rely on .net 35 features in your code. If not you can recompile with the project settings targetting .net 3.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET 3.5 framework has two different installers to choose from: the bootstrapper and the full package.

The bootstrapper installer is small in size (2.7 MB). It's small because it downloads the required files from the internet when executed on the target machine. Depending upon the target's network bandwidth, it may take a long time to run.

The full package installer is large (237 MB), and does not require an internet connection to run.
If you are currently using the bootstrapper installer, you should try downloading the full package installer and running that on the target machines.

(That is, if you actually need .NET 3.5)

You can select either installer from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569263.aspx).